# How to set .Count function to exclude headers?

Tags: vba, excel, random

I am trying to make a sub where the macro counts all the rows containing data (it isn't a set amount, it varies) and then picks a random number between 6 (to exclude headers) and the number of counted rows and highlights the corresponding row. Unfortunately the code I've been working on doesn't do what I need it to do. It does select and highlight a random row, but it selects empty rows too, not only the ones with data. Any ideas where I went wrong?

```
Sub RandomRow()
Dim mrg As Worksheet
Dim Count As Integer, myRange As Range
Set mrg = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Merged")


    mrg.Range("A6:K200000").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'reset cell colours

        Set myRange = mrg.Columns("A:A")
        Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)

myValue = Int((Count * Rnd) + 6)    ' Generate random value between 6 and the number of filled rows'.

mrg.Range("A" & myValue).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153) 'highlight a random row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current value you have for count is misleading. Say it is 20, and the rows extend to 200; you cannot use the value 20 to identify the occupied rows amongst the 200 (unless you created a map/array to store all of the occupied row-numbers, and then choose randomly from these).

You could still determine the `CountA` if this information is useful to you, but not as part of the random selection process. Better to just find where the last occupied cell is, using `End(xlUp)`.

Now you know the range containing the occupied cells and can choose randomly between these rows. Repeat the generation of a random number until you discover a cell/row that is not empty.

```
Sub RandomRow()

    Dim wsMerged As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim count As Long
    Dim randRow As Long
    Dim occupied As Boolean

    Set wsMerged = Worksheets("Merged")

    wsMerged.Range("A6:K200000").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'reset cell colours

    Set myRange = wsMerged.Columns("A:A")

    'count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)

    count = Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row - 6

    Randomize   'necessary when using Rnd()

    Do
        randRow = CLng((count * Rnd()) + 6)
        'if the cell isn't empty
        If wsMerged.Range("A" & randRow).Value <> "" Then
            'flag that we are done
            occupied = True
            wsMerged.Range("A" & randRow).Resize(1, 11).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
        End If
    Loop While Not occupied

End Sub
```

To clear cell colours I would set `.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone`.

Comment: Yep this worked perfectly, seems that the code is a bit more difficult than I anticipated.

Comment: Yes, the count of non-blanks isn't directly helpful on its own, as it doesn't tell you which rows are referred to, nor how far they extend.

Answer (score 0):

At first MyValue is not declared.

```
Dim MyValue as Long
```

Now, its better. Secondly, your macro highlight all row, but clear colors only from A to K column. You would rather highlight first 11 columns, wouldn't you?

```
mrg.Range("A" & myValue).Resize(1, 11).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
```

And, to answer your question, set myRange like that:

```
 Set myRange = mrg.Range("A6:A200000")
```

Then your Count worksheet function will not count headings actually. I hope, this helped.

Comment: This will still highlight empty rows between 6 and 200000.

Comment: Not really. If the range is continuous, WorksheetFunction.CountIf will return just the address number of the last row minus 6.

Comment: Yes, if the range is continuous then there won't be any empty rows. It seems to me that @Rhyfelwr 's could contain empty rows.